# Remove duplicates from PHP array (array_unique)

Tags: php, array-unique

I am getting a specific field from 4 different tables.

```
<?php 

//I connect to the database and the 4 tables

// Location of CSV  
$location = 'path.csv';

// List creation that will be updated with the fields and be put into my CSV file
$list = array();

// Read csv file to avoid adding duplicates
$file = fopen($location, 'r');
$data = array();

while($row = fgetcsv($file)) 
{
   $data[] = $row;
}

// Query 1
$sql = ('select distinct(field) as field from '.$table1.'');

// Run the query
$query = $Db->query($sql);

// Check for SQL errors
if ($Db->error) 
{
    return ($Db->error);
}

// Put data in the list
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    array_push($list,array($row['field'], ''));
}

// Query 2
$sql = ('select distinct(field) as field from '.$table2.'');

// Run the query
$query = $Db->query($sql);

// Check for SQL errors
if ($Db->error) 
{
    return ($Db->error);
}

// Put data in the list
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    array_push($list,array($row['field'], ''));
}

// Query 3
$sql = ('select distinct(field) as field from '.$table3.'');

// Run the query
$query = $Db->query($sql);

// Check for SQL errors
if ($Db->error) 
{
    return ($Db->error);
}

// Put data in the list
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    array_push($list,array($row['field'], ''));
}

// Query 4
$sql = ('select distinct(field) as field from '.$table4.'');

// Run the query
$query = $Db->query($sql);

// Check for SQL errors
if ($Db->error) 
{
    return ($Db->error);
}

// Put data in the list
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    array_push($list,array($row['field'], ''));
}


// Save list in the csv file without overwriting
$fp = fopen($location, 'a');

foreach (array_unique($list) as $fields) 
{
    if (in_array($fields, $data)) 
    {
        echo "Duplicate found";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Save to file";
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }           
}

fclose($fp);    

?>
```

In the end I check if the fields are already in the file. The only problem is that I still have duplicates because some tables might have exactly the same field. So, I want to remove the duplicates from the PHP array "list".

I am using :

```
$cleanlist = array_unique($list);
```

but I am getting an error:

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

More specifically the change in my code is :

```
    $cleanlist = array_unique($list);

// Save list in the csv file without overwriting
$fp = fopen($location, 'a');

foreach ($cleanlist as $fields) 
{
    if (in_array($fields, $data)) 
    {
        echo "Duplicate found";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Save to file";
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce amount of code a lot by using UNION in SELECT statement.

```
SELECT field FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field FROM table2
UNION
SELECT field FROM table3
UNION
SELECT field FROM table4
```

UNION returns distinct results by default.

Comment: Great solution. It saves loads of lines! I posted an answer too but your is better. Mine is just a way to use array_unique for a n-dimension table.

Answer (score 2):

As explain in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php), `array_unique` compares elements as strings by default. You are getting this error because PHP is trying to convert an Array to string. You have a 2D array, an array of array.

You can use the flag `SORT_REGULAR` to compare the elements as they are.
But be careful, only same key/value pairs are considered identicals.

Answer (score 0):

That worked :

```
$list = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $list)));
```

The `$list` is a 2d array.